# issue while using jimp and gm npm modules to buffer the same image in discord js bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js, gm

hello i  tried   using  gm and jimp modules to buffer the same image on discord.js  jimp for  adding img(the user avatar)  and  gm for adding   a text (the user  username)   but i fail because i cannot  find a way to make gm identify the buffer result of  jimp and edit it again and send it  i tried this code below

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Jimp = require("jimp");
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true})

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) =>
{

    let GuildMember = message.mentions.members.first();

    if(!GuildMember)
    {
        return await message.reply(" must mention someone!");
    }

    message.channel.startTyping();

    var GetUserAvatar = (GuildMember.user.avatarURL === null) ? GuildMember.user.defaultAvatarURL : GuildMember.user.avatarURL;

    var i1 = Jimp.read(GetUserAvatar);
    var i2 = Jimp.read("./images/why.jpeg");
    var FontSize = (GuildMember.user.username.length >= 20) ? 14 : 20;

    Promise.all([i1, i2]).then(async images =>
    {
        await images[0].scaleToFit(120, 120).quality(100);
        await images[1].composite(images[0], 30, 140).quality(100).getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_PNG, async (err, buffer) =>
        {
            if(err)
            {
                return console.log("error ==>> " + err).then(()=> message.channel.stopTyping(true)).catch(err => message.channel.stopTyping(true));
            }


        });



    });
    var images = images;
    await gm(images)
    .font("Helvetica.ttf", FontSize)
    .fill("#111111")
    .stroke("#800000")
    .draw(["rotate -55 text -430, 480 '" + GuildMember.user.username.trim() + "'"])
    .toBuffer(images, async function (err, buffer)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            return console.log("error ==>> " + err).then(()=> message.channel.stopTyping(true)).catch(err => message.channel.stopTyping(true));
        }

        await message.channel.send(new Discord.Attachment(buffer, images)).then(()=> message.channel.stopTyping(true)).catch(err => message.channel.stopTyping(true));
    });
};

module.exports.help =
{
    name: "what"
};
```